# A conjecture for the golden ration via continued fraction $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples, conjectures, continued-fractions, golden-ratio

Playing with my own question [Got a factored version of the Taylor's series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4738155/got-a-factored-version-of-the-taylors-series/4774119#4774119)  I found that :

Define :

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-2/x}}$$

Then it seems we have :

$$\phi=f(f(\cdots f(\phi)\cdots))$$

Numerical checking is agree so some question :

edit :

I'm really interested by an generalization the next polynomial are :

$$x^4-2x^3+2x,x^5-3x^3+2x,...$$

How to (dis)prove it ? How fast is the convergence if true ? Is there a generalization if true ?

Comment: We just have $f(\phi)=\phi$ , not really exciting. Applying $f$ gives a constant sequence.

Comment: Why did you delete your  previous question ? It was an interesting problem.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici reopen and see the edit

Comment: @Peter so have you an idea to generalize ?

Comment: What exactly is your conjecture? As mentioned above, $\phi=f(f(\cdots f(\phi)\cdots))$ is trivially true because $f(\phi)=\phi$. What generalizations are you thinking of? What are the polynomials $x^4-2x^3+2x,x^5-3x^3+2x$ and what would be the next one? What exactly do you want prove or disprove?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=(x-2/x)^{-1/2}$, define $f_0=f$ and $f_n=f\circ f_{n-1}$.

Note that we do have $f_n(\phi)\to\phi$ simply because $f(\phi)=\phi$, i.e. $f_n(\phi)$ is a constant sequence. The more interesting question would be

$$\text{does $f_n(x)\to\phi$ for $x\neq\phi$ ?}$$

A simple find is $\psi=1-\sqrt5$ since $f(\psi)=\phi$. For all other $x\neq\phi$ or $\psi$, either $f_n$ diverges or $f_n$ is not well-defined. To see this, note that if $x\geq0$, then $f_2(x)$ will not be well-defined for $x\leq\sqrt2$ or $x\geq\sqrt3$, hence we shall only focus on $x\in(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$. On this range, define the difference
$$g(x)=|f(x)-\phi|-|x-\phi|=\big(2\phi-f(x)-x\big)\text{sgn}(x-\phi).$$
It is not hard to verify $g(x)>0$ for all $x\in(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$ with $x\neq\phi$. This means every time we apply $f$, the distance to $\phi$ becomes larger and thus $f_n$ will diverge. To summarise, for positive $x\neq\phi$ either $f_n$ diverges or $f_n$ is not well-defined. As for all negative $x\neq1-\sqrt5$, we have $f(x)\geq0$ and $f(x)\neq\phi$, therefore the same argument for positive $x$ applies.

In addition, note that $\phi$ is the only possible limit point for $f_n$, since a limit point $x$ must satisfy $f(x)=x$ which yields only one solution $x=\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
f(\phi)&=\frac1{\sqrt{\phi-\frac2\phi}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\phi}{\sqrt{\phi^2-2}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\phi}{\sqrt{\phi+1-2}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\phi}{\sqrt{\phi-1}}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\phi}{\sqrt{\phi^{-1}}}\\
&=\phi
\end{align}$$
So that means continued fraction is just $\phi+\underline{0}?$